# Relation between Filesystem Hierarchy Standard and the Root Filesystem

Tags: filesystems, root-filesystem

To me, it is seems like that the Root Filesystem is an implementation of the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard. Is it correct, or the relationship between the two concepts is somewhat different?

Answer (score 0):

The relationship is a little different. The root file system contains the minimal files necessary for an operating system to install smoothly. It is very important for the operating system that the root filesystem is not damaged. For example, a library in / bin / lib, which is a hierarchy of the root filesystem, that is hosted in the filesystem hierarchy has been deleted. Your system will either continue to boot or stay on the boot screen. In this case, by changing the user level on the grub screen, you can bypass the deleted file on your system and open it in a minimal version and provide the necessary edits. As you can see, you can always recover the operating system and your data as long as the root directory is intact.

The root filesystem is represented by "/", and under it is the file hierarchy system. For example "/" + "bin"

In summary, the Root Directory is the trunk of a tree, and all the files under it are its branches. When the operating system is booted, these branches are mounted to the root directory.

I recommend you to read the FHS and Root Directory articles on the subject, please comment for your questions.